# ProgressBar looks different on different machines with same code

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a Visual Studio 2015 WPF application that contains a progress bar. Everything works fine, the problem is the progress bar looks 2-D on my machine but when ran on a different machine with VS 2015 and the same code, the progress bar is 3-D. Is there a setting in VS 2015 that controls this?

Comment: You probably have a different version of Windows and/or a different theme set on the other computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the Windows Theme forced a different look for Windows in general. Wich also affects the ProgressBar. UI Elements are designed to accept those settings from Windows.

If it looked "2D" that propably means Aero was turned off on your machine, but not the test machine. It might be possible to disable that the bar is themed, but why would you? It is purely for display purpsoes and would propably irritate the user if your Programm did not follow the pattern.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. To the why would you, I am still new to programming in general, therefore I did not know Windows Theme can do that to VS 2015 and was curious why there was a difference in look on different machines. One thing to note is my machine is Windows 10 and the other is Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @OscarT: We have 3 mayor Themes: Pre Vista/7 or Vista/7 with Aero turned off. Vista/7 with Aero turned on(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero). And in Windows 8/10 we have Metro (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_(design_language)), wich is actually a full design language. It was Windows attempt to get into the mobile OS market, but utterly failed.